React Native code deleting the last post's ID, regardless of which post's delete option is triggered
it is giving the one id(last post id)  on each post. when i try to delete any post it delete the last one
                       style={styles.modelOptions}
                            onPress={() => {
                              deletePrompt(post._id);
                              console.log(post._id);
                            }}

this is the code
{posts?.map((post, i) => (

                    <Model
                      isVisible={isModalVisible}
                      onSwipeComplete={() => toggleModal()}
                      swipeDirection="down"
                      onBackdropPress={() => toggleModal()}
                      hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
                      backdropOpacity={0.1}
                      style={{ margin: 0 }}
                    >
                      <View style={styles.modelContainer}>
                        {/*Model Options*/}
                        <View style={styles.modelContent}>
                      
                           {/* --------delete post---------- */}
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.modelOptions}
                          
                              onPress={() => {
                              deletePrompt(post._id);
                               console.log(post._id);
                             }}**
                          >
                            <AntDesign
                              name="delete"
                              style={{ fontSize: 22 }}
                            />
                            <View>
                              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Delete</Text>
                              <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: "gray" }}>
                                This will delete your post permanently
                              </Text>
                            </View>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    </Model>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
      </View>
    ))}

deleting the last post's ID, regardless of which post's delete option is triggered.
